# Como resolver o erro: illegal static declaration

Tags: java, classes

Tenho 2 classes que funcionam bem independentes uma da outra. Juntei as 2 numa só e obtive 3 erros de compilação, a mensagem de erro diz:

```
 ilegal static declaration.
```

como resolver o erro nas linhas 42, 58 6 69.

O código a seguir:

```
import java.util.*;

public class nesTudo
{
       class UserInfo 
       {
           String user; String pass; String secretCode;

   ArrayList <UserInfo> InfoList = new ArrayList<UserInfo> ();  

        public void userInternalDatabase (UserInfo info) 
        {
        this.user = info.user;
        this.pass = info.pass;
        this.secretCode = info.secretCode;
        }
    public void addUser(String i, String j, String k) 
        {
           UserInfo newUser = new UserInfo();
           newUser.user = i;
       newUser.pass = j;
           newUser.secretCode = k;
           InfoList.add(newUser);
        }

         public Object findUsername(String a)  
         {    
              for (int i=0; i <InfoList.size(); i++) 
              {
                if (InfoList.get(i).user.equals(a))
                {
                    return "This user already exists in our database.";
                    }
                  }
                    return "NÃO EXISTE ESSE UTILIZADOR."; 
              } 
   }

   class DadosGuardados
 {

        private static int lerNumero(Scanner kb, String mensagem, String mensagemErro) 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
               System.out.println(mensagem);
                try 
                {
                return Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
                } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            {
               System.out.println(mensagemErro);
            }
       }
    }

      private static boolean lerSimNao(Scanner kb, String mensagem, String mensagemErro) 
      {
          while (true) 
          {
             System.out.println(mensagem);
             String x = kb.nextLine();
             if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) return true;
             if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) return false;
             System.out.println(mensagemErro);
           } 
      }
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Bem-vindo, utilizador.");
                boolean maisRecarga = true;
                   while (maisRecarga) 
               {
                          int recarga = lerNumero(kb, "Introduza o número da recarga: ", "Isso que você digitou não era um número. Por favor, tente novamente.");
                        System.out.println("Você digitou " + recarga + ".");
                        maisRecarga = lerSimNao(kb, "Tem mais recarga para registar?\nResponda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar: ", "Era para você responder S ou N! Por favor, tente novamente.");  

                   }
                System.out.println("Obrigado, até o próximo registro.");
            }
 }
}
```

Comment: Não temos os números, tem que informar quais são as linhas. mas já adianto que deve ser para tirar o `static` como o erro está informando nelas. O problema pode ser mais embaixo. (Juntar coisas) **programar não costuma ser só copiar e colar códigos sem entender o que eles fazem**. Uma classe que tem `Tudo` no nome me parece suspeita tb. O código parece bem confuso.

Comment: @bigown mencionei as linhas 42, 58 e 69.

Comment: Onde? não estou vendo. Só tem os números que não significam nada pra gente.

Comment: @bigown aceito que o códico seja confuso excepto ser supeito.

Comment: Então é comprovadamente uma classe que faz mais do que devia mesmo :P

Answer (score 1):

Para que uma Sub Classe tenha métodos estáticos, ela precisa ser estática também!

Sua Sub classe `DadosGuardados` possui 2 métodos estáticos (além do `main`) e ela não é estática!

Tente declarar da seguinte forma :

```
static class DadosGuardados
```

Ressalto o que foi dito nos comentários !

> programar não costuma ser só copiar e colar códigos sem entender o que
>   eles fazem

A principio esta alteração deve funcionar !

Mas sugiro que remova os métodos estáticos, e crie instancias das Sub classes!

Deixe seu método `public static void main(String[] args)` na classe principal.

Comment: a alteração funciounou.